# Working on an old.reddit webscraping project, How do I make it read the description of the post too?

Tags: python, web-scraping, reddit

The code for this project is on replit.com How do I add the description?

I know this is my first post btw, so I do not know If I made this question correctly.
When I tried to fix it myself it either just didn’t give the post_desc or just decided to put the intro for the subreddit in there
I tried the normal stuff like

```
post_content = soup.find_all(“p”, class_=“md”)
```

And

```
Post_description = soup.find_all(“div”, class_=“p”)
```

And it didn't work; how could I fix this?

If you do not want to go on replit here is the code

```
import os
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from gtts import gTTS

def reset_folder(base_folder):
    try:
        os.rmdir(base_folder)
        print(f"Previous data removed.")
    except OSError as e:
        print(f"Error: {e}")

def fetch_reddit_data(subreddit_name, num_posts):
    # Reset option
    reset_option = input("Do you want to reset existing data? (y/n): ").lower()
    if reset_option == 'y':
        reset_folder(f"videos_{subreddit_name}")

    url = f"https://old.reddit.com/r/{subreddit_name}/"
    response = requests.get(url, headers={"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0"})

    if response.status_code == 200:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
        post_authors = soup.find_all("a", class_="author")
        post_titles = soup.find_all("a", class_="title")
        post_content = soup.find_all("div", class_="md")
        post_urls = [a['href'] for a in soup.find_all('a', href=True, class_='title')]

        # Display hot posts for user selection
        for i in range(min(num_posts, len(post_titles), len(post_authors))):
            print(f"({i + 1}): {post_titles[i].text} (Author: {post_authors[i].text})")

        # Prompt user to choose posts
        chosen_posts_input = input("Enter the numbers of the posts you want to use (comma-separated): ")
        chosen_posts_indices = [int(index) - 1 for index in chosen_posts_input.split(',')]

        # Validate user input
        if any(index < 0 or index >= min(num_posts, len(post_titles), len(post_authors)) for index in chosen_posts_indices):
            print("Invalid post index. Exiting.")
            return

        # Create a folder for the selected posts
        folder_name = f"videos_{subreddit_name}"
        os.makedirs(folder_name, exist_ok=True)

        for chosen_post_index in chosen_posts_indices:
            post_url = f"https://old.reddit.com{post_urls[chosen_post_index]}"
            post_content = fetch_post_content(post_url)
            text_content = f"{post_titles[chosen_post_index].text}\n\n{post_content}\n\nAuthor: {post_authors[chosen_post_index].text}"
            create_video_folder(folder_name, chosen_post_index, text_content)
    else:
        print(f"Error: Unable to fetch data from Reddit. Status code: {response.status_code}")

def fetch_post_content(post_url):
    response = requests.get(post_url, headers={"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0"})
    if response.status_code == 200:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
        # Adjust the following line based on the correct class or tag for post content
        post_content = soup.find("div", class_="md").text
        return post_content
    else:
        print(f"Error: Unable to fetch post content. Status code: {response.status_code}")
        return ""

def create_video_folder(base_folder, post_index, text_content):
    video_folder = os.path.join(base_folder, f"video{post_index}")
    os.makedirs(video_folder, exist_ok=True)

    # Save text content as captions in a .txt file
    captions_file_path = os.path.join(video_folder, "captions.txt")
    with open(captions_file_path, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as captions_file:
        captions_file.write(text_content)

    # Convert text to speech and save as an audio file
    audio_file_path = os.path.join(video_folder, "output.mp3")
    tts = gTTS(text=text_content, lang='en-uk', slow=False)
    tts.save(audio_file_path)
    print(f"Text and descriptions converted to speech and saved as {audio_file_path}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    subreddit_name = input("Enter the name of the subreddit: ")
    num_posts = int(input("Enter the number of hot posts to fetch: "))

    fetch_reddit_data(subreddit_name, num_posts)
```

I do not know if this is the right website for this but I need help!!!

Comment: could you provide a small html sample?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend to add `.json` to Reddit URL to get the data not in HTML format but in Json format which is easier to parse, e.g.:

```py
from html import unescape

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:121.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/121.0"
}

url = "https://old.reddit.com/r/python/.json"  # <-- note the .json at the end of the URL

data = requests.get(url, headers=headers).json()
for l in data["data"]["children"]:
    print(l["data"]["title"])
    print()
    print(BeautifulSoup(unescape(l["data"]["selftext_html"]), "html.parser").text)
    print("-" * 80)
```

Prints:

```
Sunday Daily Thread: What's everyone working on this week?

Weekly Thread: What's Everyone Working On This Week? ️
Hello /r/Python! It's time to share what you've been working on! Whether it's a work-in-progress, a completed masterpiece, or just a rough idea, let us know what you're up to!
How it Works:

Show & Tell: Share your current projects, completed works, or future ideas.
Discuss: Get feedback, find collaborators, or just chat about your project.
Inspire: Your project might inspire someone else, just as you might get inspired here.

Guidelines:

Feel free to include as many details as you'd like. Code snippets, screenshots, and links are all welcome.
Whether it's your job, your hobby, or your passion project, all Python-related work is welcome here.

Example Shares:

Machine Learning Model: Working on a ML model to predict stock prices. Just cracked a 90% accuracy rate!
Web Scraping: Built a script to scrape and analyze news articles. It's helped me understand media bias better.
Automation: Automated my home lighting with Python and Raspberry Pi. My life has never been easier!

Let's build and grow together! Share your journey and learn from others. Happy coding! 

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Thursday Daily Thread: Python Careers, Courses, and Furthering Education!

Weekly Thread: Professional Use, Jobs, and Education 
Welcome to this week's discussion on Python in the professional world! This is your spot to talk about job hunting, career growth, and educational resources in Python. Please note, this thread is not for recruitment.

How it Works:

Career Talk: Discuss using Python in your job, or the job market for Python roles.
Education Q&A: Ask or answer questions about Python courses, certifications, and educational resources.
Workplace Chat: Share your experiences, challenges, or success stories about using Python professionally.


Guidelines:

This thread is not for recruitment. For job postings, please see r/PythonJobs or the recruitment thread in the sidebar.
Keep discussions relevant to Python in the professional and educational context.


Example Topics:

Career Paths: What kinds of roles are out there for Python developers?
Certifications: Are Python certifications worth it?
Course Recommendations: Any good advanced Python courses to recommend?
Workplace Tools: What Python libraries are indispensable in your professional work?
Interview Tips: What types of Python questions are commonly asked in interviews?


Let's help each other grow in our careers and education. Happy discussing! 

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

...
```

Comment: Thank You!! I got the project up and running because of the JSON file help. Now the only thing I have to do is change out the TTS for a better one!